# I can not create an emulator in Android AVD Manager

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to create an Android emulator and when I open the AVD Manager and attempt to create one it keeps saying, "No target selected." Even when I select a target.

http://bit.ly/15vr9fk

Comment: Do you have that SDK installed on your computer?

Answer (score 10):

Faced the same issue,

I checked the Android SDK Manager and found that `ARM EABI v7a System Image` what not installed.

[image]

After installation I had to *restart* my Eclipse and then I was able to create a new emulator.

Comment: +1 for good explanation. I did not know if I should install just the SDK Platform.

Answer (score 5):

You are getting the error "no system images installed for this target". Launch the SDK manager and install one or more system images under API 17

Comment: I needed to restart Eclipse after the installation, for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Closed the program, uninstalled the SDK from the SDK Manager and installed it again. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

to solve the problem.
install one of CPU System Images.
for example: ARM EABI v7a System Image