# "No Target Selected" error on Android tablet emulator in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am learning Android programming using Eclipse, but am unable to create a tablet emulator.  I have successfully created numerous phone emulators, which all work fine.

When I try to create a tablet emulator in the Android Virtual Device manager I get the error: "No Target Selected", even though it puts a target in itself when I select the device from the dropdown, and I do have that image installed.

Here is a screenshot. The only setting which I have added is the name - all others are the automatic settings which appear when I select the Nexus 10 from the dropdown menu.  By this I mean that the Target is set automatically when I select the Nexus 10, as are the Memory options, internal storage, etc.

[image]

I have also tried using different Targets - both Android and Google API's for  14,15,16,17,18 and 19.  None of them worked though. The one shown in the screenshot is the default which comes up when I select Nexus 10 device.

Also (this is an edit - forgot to mention before) I tried it with the CPU/ABI set to each of the possibilities in that dropdown (tried all of them for each and every API version), but again without success.

Here's a screenshot of the relevent images and API's etc. which I have installed:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here, and how I can get a tablet emulator running?  There are several other similar questions on here, but I have tried the answers, such as making sure I have that API level 16 image installed, restarting eclipse, deleting and reinstalling the emulator, deleting and reinstalling the SDK, deleting and reinstalling the API image and so on.  I've run out of things to reinstall.

This is happening with all my tablet emulators, not just the nexus 10.

Any helpful advice will be most greatly appreciated.

Comment: why don't you set CPU/API as well ?

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to mention that.  I have also tried with and without CPU/ABI set, to all available settings, but it made no difference on any of them.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Have you tried without using the Nexus 10 or any Device selection?

Comment: Yes - it works fine for smaller sizes, just can't get it working for the tablet ones.

Comment: I'v found answer in this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764569/i-can-not-create-an-emulator-in-android-avd-manager

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion Natalia, however sadly I already have the ARM EABI v7a System Image installed, as that post suggests.  In my case it did not help.  Back to the old drawing board..

Comment: `android list target` does not show any target with a [WQXGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution#WQXGA_.282560x1600.29) skin

Comment: I have created a nexus 10 emulator on eclipse 4.3.2 and SDK updated and everything works fine. Have you tried again since that time?

Comment: Hey Sulfkain, No I haven't tried again lately.  I'll have a play with the latest Eclipse and see if it works for me now also.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make RAM to 2048 and select Use Host GPU. It works for me. Need more RAM owing to resolution of virtual device. You may get error from host machine if it has less memory installed